# Java Spring how to check if two objects are equal and one of them is LAZY loaded

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I try to compare two objects - one of them is LAZY loaded:

```
@Entity
public class Path{
 public void removePoint(Point point) {
if (point.getPath() != null && point.getPath() != this) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Point %s does not belong to path%s", point, this));
        }
        point.setPath(null);
        this.getPoints().remove(point);
    }
}
```

Check:

```
window.getPath().removePoint(point);
```

The problem is that these two objects don't have the same reference: `point.getPath()` and `this`

The question is if the reason why these 2 obejcts have different references is that one of them is LAZY loaded (sth like `Path$HibernateProxy$Di4Siuwn@32825`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If objects are lazily loaded then they will not be the actual entity class that you defined but rather a proxy implementation as you have now found `Path$HibernateProxy$Di4Siuwn@32825`
In general in java you shou use equals method to compare objects. Hibernate entities may require some additional treatment to help with equality comparison. Please review this article in detail
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-entities-equality-and-identity/

Comment: thank you very much for your answer - I think that's the answer I'm looking for:)  Excellent article!